# RTK Query: Set baseUrl from store

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I have an app that contains a store:

```js
const initialState: GlobalState = {
  data: {
    isOnboardingCompleted: 'unknown',
    isEnvironmentReady: false,
    environmentConfig: ProdEnvConfig,
    // ...
  },
}
```

The key `environmentConfig` contains an object where the baseUrl is stored.
The environment config can change while the app is running. User is able to select different ones.

When creating my api:

```js
export const BaseApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'base-api',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: '',
  }),
  endpoints: builder => ({
    getStudents: builder.query({
      query: param => {
        return "/students"
      },
    }),
  }),
});
```

How can I set the baseUrl while also **listening** to changes to `environmentConfig` and re-setting the baseUrl from the store?

I am imagining some pseudo-code like this which I can't seem to make work:

```js
const listen = () => {
  const config = store.getState().global.data.environmentConfig

  BaseApi.setBaseUrl(config.baseUrl)
}

store.subscribe(listen)
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: are you trying to keep all the existing state, cache, etc. after you change the base URL?

Comment: @ChrisDanna no, ideally a clean api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you could write a small wrapper around the `fetchBaseQuery` function and pass in a `baseUrl` that is stored in the Redux store.

Example:

```js
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";

const baseQuery = (baseQueryArgs = {}) => async (
  fetchArgs = {},
  api,
  extraOptions = {},
) => {
  const { getState } = api;
  const state = getState();
  const baseUrl = state.baseUrl;

  return fetchBaseQuery({
    ...baseQueryArgs,
    baseUrl,
  })(fetchArgs, api, extraOptions);
};
```

```js
export const BaseApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'base-api',
  baseQuery: baseQuery(),
  endpoints: builder => ({
    getStudents: builder.query({
      query: param => {
        return "/students"
      },
    }),
  }),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@Drew's answer is right but I have here my typed answer that accepts one extra param `{ environmentUrlKey }` that gets me the right `baseUrl` depending on the passed key.

`createDynamicBaseQuery` gets called every time an api-call is going to happen and gets the latest values in the store (e.g. accessToken or baseUrl).

```js
type EnvirontmentKey = keyof EnvironmentConfig;

type CreateDynamicQuery = (
  args: any,
  api: BaseQueryApi,
  extraOptions: object,
  { environmentUrlKey }: { environmentUrlKey: EnvirontmentKey },
) => MaybePromise<QueryReturnValue<unknown, FetchBaseQueryError, object>>;

export const createDynamicBaseQuery: CreateDynamicQuery = async (
  args,
  api,
  extraOptions,
  { environmentUrlKey },
) => {
  const rootState = api.getState() as RootState;

  const baseUrl = rootState.global.data.environmentConfig[environmentUrlKey]; // I have multiple apis and pass the key to each it being alpha, beta, or prod

  if (!baseUrl) {
    throw new Error('Missing API_BASE_URL');
  }

  const rawBaseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl,
    prepareHeaders: headers => {
      const accessToken = rootState.user.data.accessToken; // or wherever you stored the accessToken

      if (accessToken) {
        headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${accessToken}`);
      }

      headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      headers.set('Accept', 'application/json');

      return headers;
    },
  });

  const query = rawBaseQuery(args, api, extraOptions);

  return query;
};
```

And this is how I call it:

```js
export const SomeBaseApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'some-base-api',
  baseQuery: (...args) =>
    createDynamicBaseQuery(...args, {
      environmentUrlKey: 'KEY_TO_YOUR_BASE_URL_IN_YOUR_ENV_CONFIG',
    }),
  endpoints: () => ({}),
});
```